# how i can fetching data in this array and if condition for make it be an cluster with minimum distance in python?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, pandas, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

I will to implement kmeans in python, but i just don't know to process min distance from euclidean distance.
i have been calculate data in 3 cluster,

this is my result array :

```
[array([4, 5], dtype=int64), 4.1231056256176606, 0, 
array([4, 8], dtype=int64), 4.4721359549995796, 0, 
array([14, 23], dtype=int64), 22.022715545545239, 0, 
array([4, 5], dtype=int64), 1.0, 1, 
array([4, 8], dtype=int64), 2.0, 1, 
array([14, 23], dtype=int64), 19.723082923316021, 1]
```

here its my code:

```
for i in range(len(centroidrandom)):
    for j in range(3):            
        jarak_=euclidean_distances(data[j],centroidrandom[:][i])
cluster.append(data[j])
 cluster.append(jarak_[0][0])
        cluster.append(i)
print(cluster)
```

Comment: It might help to refine your question in a way that data is included that helps to reporduce your problem easily.

Comment: these data=[[4,5],[4,8],[14,23]]

Comment: So can you include the data into the code in a way that it shows your problem?

Comment: Have a look here for an example: http://glowingpython.blogspot.de/2012/04/k-means-clustering-with-scipy.html

Comment: @BARIANTO Improved formatting, please use Drag & Ctrl+K to format your code next time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some example code for kmeans clustering with three clusters, modified from the example given in the comment above:

```
from pylab import plot,show
from numpy import vstack,array
from numpy.random import rand
from scipy.cluster.vq import kmeans,vq


# data generation for three sets of data
data = vstack((rand(150,2) + array([.5,.5]),rand(150,2), rand(150,2) + array([0,.5])))

# computing K-Means with K = 3 (3 clusters)
centroids,_ = kmeans(data,3)
# assign each sample to a cluster
idx,_ = vq(data,centroids)
print idx

# some plotting using numpy's logical indexing
plot(data[idx==0,0],data[idx==0,1],'ob',
     data[idx==1,0],data[idx==1,1],'or',
     data[idx==2,0],data[idx==2,1],'oy')
plot(centroids[:,0],centroids[:,1],'sg',markersize=8)
show()
```

[image]